# How to run react-cli project in expo-cli?

Tags: react-native

I have downloaded a react-cli project from github and copied the necessary files from it and paste it to empty expo project and when I am running npm start, I am facing issues. Is there a way to run react-cli project in expo project?

I did npm install and installed all necessary packages but still I could not able to run my project in expo. Is there a way to do this?

I am a beginner so, I don't have hands on react-cli. I want to execute that react-cli in expo-cli. Please help me with this. Please tell me the procedure after downloading a react-cli project from github.

Comment: Short answer: it's "mostly" not possible. This is something like ejecting an expo project, then later trying to use expo on the same project. Some of the dependencies/native modules aren't compatible

Comment: there maybe be someway.